# escape hyphen in a bash postgresql psql command line

Tags: bash, postgresql

How can I escape a probable hyphen in a comand line like the following:

```
$ for i in db1 db2 db1-db2; do su - postgres -c "psql -c \"alter database \"$i\" with connection limit = 0;\""; done

ALTER DATABASE


ALTER DATABASE ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-" at character 19 LINE 1: alter database db1-db2 with connection limit = 0;
                      ^
```

Comment: Why is `db1-db2` there on the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "quoting hell" can be somehow alleviated by providing the SQL in standard input as a [here-string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

In your case I think this should do the job:

```
for i in db1 db2 db1-db2; do su - postgres -c "(psql <<EOF
alter database \"$i\" with connection limit = 0;
EOF
)"; done
```

Comment: if you're going to use a here string (good idea imho), it can be fed "through" su rather than interpolated: equivalent to `echo 'alter database "'$i'" with...' | su - postgres -c psql`

Comment: You can pipe the output of the for loop to su/psql, too, rather than doing a su on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 3):

this will do it :

```
for i in db1 db2 db1-db2 
  do 
   su - postgres -c "psql -c \"alter database \\\"$i\\\" with connection limit = 0;\"" 
  done
```

The problem isn't in escaping the hyphen, the problem is that you have a string in a string. therefore, you have to escape once for the su command, and once for the psql command.

this if you don't like multiple escaped sequence.

```
for i in db1 db2 db1-db2 
  do 
   su - postgres -c "psql -c 'alter database \"$i\" with connection limit = 0;'" 
  done
```

by using ' singelquotes and " dbl quotes, you have less escaping to do. ;-)